# Trying to print comma separated values retrieved from MySQL with group_concat into csv file with php

Tags: php, foreach, codeigniter-3, export-to-csv, group-concat

***I am trying to print output on csv file expected as below:***

[image]

***But it prints unexpected like below:***

[image: ![enter image description here]

OR when I don't use explode function to split comma seperated into array (as used within below foreach for the column "tezest") it just prints comma seperated values as below in all the fields of exported csv file:

exe1, example1@gmail.com, example1, 1234567890, 11
exe2, example2@gmail.com, example2, 2222567890, 12

***When I print_f values shown are correct using below code:***

*Code -->*

```
    $this->data['report_results'] = $this->Task_model->getReports($data);

    $this->data['reports_name'] = $this->Task_model->getFormName('form198');
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->data['report_results']);die('qq');
```

*Output -->*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => exe1
            [form_id] => form198
            [created_at] => 2020-09-13 13:14:29
            [fillup_id] => 64654b4040f57c827c75edc0e8
            [tezest] => exe1, example1@gmail.com, example1, 1234567890, 11
            [formName] => Admission Form
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => 12
            [form_id] => form198
            [created_at] => 2020-09-13 13:15:20
            [fillup_id] => b9c2259b74eb5c97aceadee956
            [tezest] => exe2, example2@gmail.com, example2, 2222567890, 12
            [formName] => Admission Form
        )

)
qq
```

***But it just prints wrong after entering foreach loop. The code with foreach loop to print to csv file is as below:***

```
<?php
$this->data['report_results'] = $this->Task_model->getReports($data);

$this->data['reports_name'] = $this->Task_model->getFormName('form198');
            
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($this->data['report_results']);die('qq');
                          
                         
            
if(!empty($this->data['report_results'])){
                
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "report_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";
    //create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    //set column headers


    $fields = array("Sl. No",  "Form name", "Token_id", "Date" ,);
    if(!empty($this->data['reports_name'])){
        foreach($this->data['reports_name'] as $question){
            $this->data['reports_name'][] = array(
                      'name' =>  $question['name']
                        
                      );
            $fields[] = $question['name'];

        }        
    }
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);


    $i=0;
                
    foreach($this->data['report_results'] as $result){      
                    
    $lineData = array(++$i,$result['roleName'],  $result['form_id'], date('d/m/Y',strtotime($result['created_at'])));  

    
    foreach($this->data['report_results'] as $question){

        $this->data['report_results'][] = array(
                                 'tezest' =>  $question['tezest']
                        
                               );
        $arr=explode(",",$question['tezest']);


        $lineData[] = $arr;
    }
                               
    fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter); 
}               
                
//move back to beginning of file
fseek($f, 0);
    
//set headers to download file rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
    
//output all remaining data on a file pointer
fpassthru($f);
                                
exit(); 
                
  }
?>
```

Please help me understand where I am wrong in achieving the the correct output.

Comment: can you please embed the images properly?

Comment: Images added, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use explode to convert comma seperated string into array:

```
$array=explode(",",$question['commaseperated-string']);
```